# Apache 2.4 loads index.html.bak/.old/... before index.php - wildcard?

Tags: apache-2.4, directoryindex

After upgrading our Apache to 2.4 something seems to have changed with Apaches behavior but I can't find out what.

Our DirectoryIndex directive:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
```

And when index.html.old or index.html.bak and index.php are inside the requested directory, apache loads index.html.old although that isn't defined in DirectoryIndex. Seems like some kind of wildcard or regex-match.

Has anyone experienced something like this too?

I am using Apache 2.4.7 from Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

We found the solution and it had to do with MultiViews:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html